# Proper way of using try catch() in C#

Tags: c#, lambda, try-catch

I am using `ASP.NET/C#`.

Here is an example where I am updating some information in database using `lambda expression`.

```
try
{
    using (var db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
    {
        var logSubGroup = db.sys_Log_Account_SubGroups
             .SingleOrDefault(subGroup => subGroup.cSubGroupName.Equals(subGroupName));
        logSubGroup.cRejectedBy = rejectedBy;
        logSubGroup.dRejectedOn = DateTime.Now;
        logSubGroup.cAuthorizedStatus = "Rejected";
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

As you can see I am not doing anything inside `catch() block`.

I know this is a terrible way of using `try catch`.

Can anyone just help me to use `try catch block` in a correct manner.

I am just clueless as to what must come inside the `catch block`.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: What is the reason for catching an Exception?
Do you want to notice, that something went wrong and message it to someone or do you want to do something if the thing in try went wrong?

If not, there are other possibilities than try-catch.

Comment: In this example I think you should check if logSubGroup is null :)  dont catch the null exception. Exceptions are exceptional. e.g. stuff you cant plan for.

Comment: @Karl What are the other possibilities than try-catch?Can you point out few?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should ideally handle the error so that your application can recover from it, at the very least though, you should log it. You should never just swallow it. Also, you shouldn't handle an exception that you don't expect or can't handle. For example, when opening a file, a FileNotFoundException can be expected and handled, for example by displaying a warning and letting the user pick another file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , you suggest that I should only handle exception when I am expecting one , is it?Thanks.

Comment: @freebird Basically, yes, because you don't know what's wrong or how to recover from the error. Your application could be in a corrupt state and destroy user data.

Comment: @freebird For exceptions that you really don't expect, it might be a good idea to still use a global exception handler in order to log/report it or give the user a more meaningful error message before the application is shut down.

Comment: So I think I will create Global.asax file for unknown errors , while I am expecting some errors , there I can handle them using try-catch blocks.Is it a good approach.Thanks.

Comment: @freebird Yes, that sounds good to me. Always remember that with unexpected exceptions, you don't know what state the program is in when one is thrown.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a try-catch block at all, unless you have a *specific reason* to catch a *specific exception*.

Instead, use one of the global exception handling methods ([Application_Error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24395wz3.aspx) in ASP.NET) to globally catch unhandled exceptions, show an error message and log the error.

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule, there is no need to catch an exception if the code catching the exception cannot do something about the problem, then continue running correctly. In code like what you've presented, can you identify some action you could take within the catch block to restore the program to a state where you trust it to continue running? If not, then just let the exception bubble up the stack.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically it's up to you to decide what kind of exception may occur inside your catch statement it's not totally wrong doing it this way of course if you are in the development phase I would highly not recommend doing try catch since you can miss some of the important exception that may occur and you would want to fix also in general you should include a message or an action that should occur if the exception or error was caught a message to the user can be notified that action did not executed well but ideally you have to let user know what went wrong so in this case better error handling is a way to go